# Liferay Service Builder + Document Library + Quartz Scheduler + Apache POI

Tags: liferay, quartz-scheduler, document-library

Hello StackOverflow Community,

**Requirement**:
I need advice and help on going about how to create a Liferay(LR) module that will create XLS files with information pulled from a DB, and store them to a folder location in Document Library(DL), during scheduled times throughout the week.

**Solution**:
I solutionized to use LR's Service Builder+DL+Quartz Scheduler+Apache POI. Code below.

**Roadblock**:
The receive() method requires a RenderRequest object so that the ThemeDisplay and ServiceContext object can be created, which will be used by the DLAppServiceUtil to create the file in DL. How do I go about creating a RenderRequest object?

```
@Override
public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
    _log.debug(">> receive()");

    ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) renderRequest.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
    fileUploadByApp("folder-1", themeDisplay, renderRequest);

    _log.debug("<< receive()");
}

public void fileUploadByApp(String folderName, ThemeDisplay themeDisplay, RenderRequest renderRequest) {

    try {
        File file = new File("D:/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6/temp/sample_" + getDateTimeBasedFilename() + ".txt");

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        writer.write("Something");
        writer.close();

        long repositoryId = themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId();
        String mimeType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);
        String title = file.getName();
        String description = "This file is added via programatically";
        String changeLog = "hi";
        Long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;

        Folder folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), parentFolderId, folderName);
        ServiceContext serviceContext = ServiceContextFactory.getInstance(DLFileEntry.class.getName(),
                renderRequest);
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(repositoryId, folder.getFolderId(), file.getName(), mimeType, title,
                description, changeLog, is, file.length(), serviceContext);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Project repo, click here](https://bitbucket.org/MrC0mm0n/lr-portal-6.2.5-ce-ga6/src/370060533c5b833535e7d4036bc389543a312dc0/test-service-builder/test-service-builder-portlet/src/main/java/com/example/plugins/?at=master)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, method `receive` doesn't require `RenderRequest` object, but your method `fileUploadByApp`. If you look carefully in your method, all what you need from `ThemeDisplay` is `scopeGroupId`. `RenderRequest` object, as you mentioned, is required for creating `ServiceContext`, but you have at least 2 solutions for this.

1. Get some instance from `ServletContextPool` (if its possible).
2. Create object manually

In second case you can setup what you need, but I think you need setup only `scopeGroupId` and it will work as you want.

Example of changes:

```java
@Override
public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
    _log.debug(">> receive()");

    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(YOUR_SCOPE_GROUP_ID); //For example YOUR_SCOPE_GROUP_ID can be received from message.
    fileUploadByApp("folder-1", serviceContext);

    _log.debug("<< receive()");
}

public void fileUploadByApp(String folderName, ServiceContext serviceContext) {

    try {
        File file = new File("D:/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga6/temp/sample_" + getDateTimeBasedFilename() + ".txt");

        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8"));
        writer.write("Something");
        writer.close();

        long repositoryId = serviceContext.getScopeGroupId();
        String mimeType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);
        String title = file.getName();
        String description = "This file is added via programatically";
        String changeLog = "hi";
        Long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;

        Folder folder = DLAppServiceUtil.getFolder(serviceContext.getScopeGroupId(), parentFolderId, folderName);

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(repositoryId, folder.getFolderId(), file.getName(), mimeType, title,
                description, changeLog, is, file.length(), serviceContext);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks glw. The code provided helped joining the dots. I've added the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks glw. The code provided helped joining the dots. I got it to work with the below solution in addition to the snippet you provided.

```
// Repository ID of the document library, figured is out by the output from
// _log.debug("repositoryId: " + repositoryId);
// in
// fileUploadByApp(folderName, themeDisplay, renderRequest).
// I found the entry in 'ddmcontent' table of LR's default DB
private long siteARepoId = ?????;
// Found this in 'company' table of LR's default DB
private long LRCompanyId = ?????;
private String sAdminRole = "Administrator";

@Override
public void receive(Message message) throws MessageListenerException {
    _log.debug(">> receive()");

    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(siteARepoId);
    fileUploadByApp(DLFolderLocation, serviceContext);

    _log.debug("<< receive()");
}

public void fileUploadByApp(String folderName, ServiceContext serviceContext) {
    _log.debug(">> fileUploadByApp(folderName, serviceContext)");

    try {
        File file = new File(LRTempLocation + "excel_" + getDateTimeBasedFilename() + ".xlsx");

        createExcel(file);

        long repositoryId = serviceContext.getScopeGroupId();
        String mimeType = MimeTypesUtil.getContentType(file);
        String title = file.getName();
        String description = "This file is added via programatically";
        String changeLog = "hi";
        Long parentFolderId = DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID;

        _log.debug("repositoryId: " + repositoryId);
        _log.debug("fileName: " + file.getName());
        _log.debug("mimeType: " + mimeType);
        _log.debug("title: " + title);
        _log.debug("description: " + description);
        _log.debug("changeLog: " + changeLog);
        _log.debug("fileLength: " + file.length());
        _log.debug("serviceContext: " + serviceContext);

        Folder folder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(repositoryId, parentFolderId, folderName);

        _log.debug("folderId: " + folder.getFolderId());

        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

        _log.debug("inputStream: " + is);

        // Initializing PermissionChecker, without the below the exception
        // occurs
        // Caused by: com.liferay.portal.security.auth.PrincipalException:
        // PermissionChecker not initialized
        // Source:
        // http://www.open.gr/blog/2014/05/permissionchecker-not-initialised-scheduler-job
        Company companyqq = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(LRCompanyId);
        Role adminRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(companyqq.getCompanyId(), sAdminRole);
        List<User> adminUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(adminRole.getRoleId());
        PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(adminUsers.get(0).getUserId());
        PermissionChecker permissionChecker = PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(adminUsers.get(0), true);
        PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);

        // Adding the file entry to the Document Library
        DLAppServiceUtil.addFileEntry(repositoryId, folder.getFolderId(), file.getName(), mimeType, title,
                description, changeLog, is, file.length(), serviceContext);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _log.debug("<< fileUploadByApp(folderName, serviceContext)");
}
```

[Project Link, click here](https://bitbucket.org/MrC0mm0n/lr-portal-6.2.5-ce-ga6/overview)